# How to rename the datatable column name without losing the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I want to rename my `DataTable` column names.

I tried this:

```
dt.Columns[8].ColumnName = "regnum";

dt.AcceptChanges();
```

but my data is lost afterwards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
dt.Columns[8].ColumnName = "regnum";
```

This just binds your `Columns[8]` to  the non-existing "regnum" column in the Db.

If you want to rename the actuals Db column, execute an SQL script.

But my guess is you actually want to change the Caption:

```
  dt.Columns[8].Caption = "regnum";
```

Comment: hmmmm, it is a stored procedure which return data without specific names:like this `(expression) (expression) ....`

Comment: please ,Could u explain more what u want to say?

Answer (score 12):

Following is the example:

```
DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn Dc = new DataColumn("Name");
DataColumn Dc1 = new DataColumn("ID");
Dt.Columns.Add(Dc);
Dt.Columns.Add(Dc1);

DataRow dr = Dt.NewRow();
dr["name"] = "1";
dr["ID"] = "111";
Dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = Dt.NewRow();
dr["name"] = "2";
dr["ID"] = "11112";
Dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "ddsxsd";
Dt.AcceptChanges();
```

I did not find any data loss!!!!!!!! Because it will merely change the column name.

**EDIT**

You can also bring your desired column names from your Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 dataTable.Columns["ExistingColumnName"].ColumnName = "regnum";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also may this code serve someone!
I have a realize that this is the easiest way just like @Henk said:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Item NO";
                        dt.Columns[1].ColumnName = "LocalCode";                       
                        dt.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Currency";
                        dt.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Menu Flag";
                        dt.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Item Class";
                        dt.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Dress Sort";
                        return dt;
                    }
```