# how to change or replace all column name in data table

Tags: c#

I am retrieving table from data base and storing in data table.

I need to change column name into new column name in data table I tried below code but its not changing..where I made mistake....

```
             foreach (DataColumn column in obj_dt.Columns)
             column.Caption = column.ColumnName.Replace("Tax","new tax");

             foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridColumn in dataGridView_dataGridView_curt_Prd_Dtls.Columns)
             gridColumn.HeaderText = obj_dt.Columns[gridColumn.HeaderText].Caption;

             dataGridView_dataGridView_curt_Prd_Dtls.DataSource = obj_dt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check the link below will helps you in finding your answer

[How to rename the datatable column name without losing the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924743/how-to-rename-the-datatable-column-name-without-losing-the-data)

[Why DataColumn.Caption doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267408/why-datacolumn-caption-doesnt-work)