# How to Change the Column Name in Datatable in C# without losing column data?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I'm using Datatable in C# just to rely it to a datagrid in WPF, the problem is when i change the column name, all the data in this column are loss, i tried [This stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924743/how-to-rename-the-datatable-column-name-without-losing-the-data) but the same problem still remain, can someone help me please?

thanks

Comment: What are you using as your data store? How are you changing the column name? Are you losing the data in the data store, or are you just renaming it in memory and then it's not mapped correctly? Same sample code would be great.

Comment: @Prescott I'm not using a data store, i'm using a datatable just as a container of a data that i will bind with a datagrid in WPF, i 'm changing the column name as following : dt.Columns["oldColumnName"].ColumnName = "newColumnName"; i loose the data in memory, thanks

Comment: I found the problem ... WPF doesn't accept datatable column name with special characters, anyway thank you @Prescott

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem ... WPF doesn't accept datatable column name with special characters, anyway thank you @Prescott